# Why does my "Rock Paper Scissors" program not work and keep crashing my page?

Tags: javascript, html, function, crash

My "Rock Paper Scissors" assignment asked for me to use very specific diameters too. It has simply not been working. Instead of any of the logged consoles coming up, the page won't even load.

I originally had all of the strings in the console as alerts that would pop up on the page, but that didn't work so I just switched it to console hoping it would pop up if I used node, but that also didn't work. I moved around the player and computer wins, in and out of the functions to see if that would change anything, but it didn't.

```js
var hands = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

function getHand(){
        return hands[parseInt(Math.random()*hands.length)%3];
}

var player1 = "Mike";
console.log("Hello " + player1);

var player2;
console.log("Player 2 is the computer!");

//var playWins = 0;
//var compWins = 0;

function playRound(){

    if (hand == computer){
        console.log("You guys tied!");

    } else if (hand == "Scissors" && computer == "Rock"){
        console.log(player1 + " has lost! Sadddd...");
        compWins++;
    } else if (hand == "Paper" && computer == "Rock"){
        console.log(player1 + " has wonnnn!!! Yay! I guess...");
        playWins++

    } else if (hand == "Rock" && computer == "Scissors"){
        console.log(player1 + " has wonnnn!!! Yay! I guess...");
        playWins++;
    } else if (hand == "Paper" && computer == "Scissors"){
        console.log(player1 + + " has lost! Sadddd...");
        compWins++;

    } else if (hand == "Rock" && computer == "Paper"){
        console.log(player1 + + " has lost! Sadddd...");
        compWins++;
    } else if (hand == "Paper" && computer == "Paper"){
        console.log(player1 + " has wonnnn!!! Yay! I guess...");
        playWins++;
    } else {console.log("There seems to be a problem.");}
}


hand = [];
computer = [];


while (hand <= 3 || computer <= 3){
    for (i = 0; i >=5; i++ ){
    hand.push(getHand());
    computer.push(getHand());

    playRound();
    }
}

if(playWins>compWins){
    console.log(player1 + " Wins!");
} else {
    console.log("Computer Wins!");
}
```

I expected it to tell me who wins each game, then who wins altogether after at least 5 matches. I can't see my error messages because the page won't even fully load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop.  A couple errors are making that happen.  First, these are arrays:

```
while (hand <= 3 || computer <= 3)
```

So I'm guessing you want to check their *length*?:

```
while (hand.length <= 3 || computer.length <= 3)
```

Then you also have a logical error here:

```
for (i = 0; i >=5; i++ ){
```

Since `i` starts as `0`, it is immediately *not* `>= 5`, so the `for` loop is never entered and the `while` loop just repeats indefinitely.  You probably want `<=`:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ){
```

You'll also want to uncomment these so the variables are defined, since you use those variables later:

```
var playWins = 0;
var compWins = 0;
```

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you. What a tragic few mistakes. But the program isn't printing out the strings for the playRound() five times. It's simply printing out whoever wins one of those games once, and then the overall winner. How can I change that?

Comment: @LolaOretade: It looks like you're trying to compare `hand` and `computer` directly.  But those are arrays.  It seems that you want to get the *last value* of each array instead?  Or maybe only track the current "play" as a string instead of arrays, and use a separate variable to count the number of times the game has been played?

Comment: So arrays can't be compared directly. Would it work for me to turn the arrays into strings at the start of the playRound function and then run it through? I'm not quite sure how I could count the wins without those arrays is all.